# C# ASP.NET Application ComboBox binded to GridView Display Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

I Am Creating a ASP.NET Web Application that will display specific Data From a SQL Database. I have Created 3 DataSources Each Specific for Data I want to view chosen from a DropDownList.

My DropDownList Coding C# Side is as followed:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string SourceName = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
            GridView1.DataSourceID = SourceName;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
```

DropDownList coding on the ASP.NET Side:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem Value="DataSource_Gerneral">General Overview</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="DataSource_Portfolio">Portfolio</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="DataSource_ErrorLog">Error Log</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

The Grid View Coding on the ASP.NET Side is as Followed:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderStyle="Inset" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="Call_Sign" DataSourceID= "DataSource_Gerneral" Font-Size="Smaller" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Height="16px" Width="155px" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" ClientIDMode="AutoID" HorizontalAlign="Justify" PageSize="100" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged1">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />



            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Call_Sign" HeaderText="Call_Sign" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Call_Sign" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Current_Price" HeaderText="Current_Price" SortExpression="Current_Price" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Stock_Market" HeaderText="Stock_Market" SortExpression="Stock_Market" />
            </Columns>



            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

I have tested the dropdownlist to make sure it was actually changing the DatasourceID. It was working properly. However When Selected view is Selected into the dropdownlist, the gridview stays the same. I have been looking for a way to display the new data. Am I missing Something! I am hoping it is only a simple line of code that will change the gridview in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I overlooked a huge game changer. I wasn't changing the right place. As all the information was coming from the same database. I had to write 3 if statements to change the command.CommandText statement. in ex.

```
If (DataName == "DataSource_General)
{
    command.CommandText = " ... Select...";
}

If (DataName == "DataSource_Portfolio")
{
    command.CommandText = " ... Select ...";
}
```

By doing that my data showed correctly. You can also do this configuring DropDownList ItemValue to the command text then calling it by:

```
String selectStatement = DropDownList.SelectedValue.ToString();
command.CommandText = selectStatement;
```

By doing this the second way, you achieve cleaner code.